# symfony / doctrine deliveres partially incorrect data - using uuids

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, uuid

I have a big problem with Symfony, Doctrine and partially incorrect data.

First of all

- i use uuids for primary keys
- i use jwts for authentication
- i use symfony 5.4.x and doctrine-bundle 2.7.x
- i use class inheriance for getting my pk on each entity
- i don´t use at all relations, because i want to have some flexibility to slice components into their origin e.g. security component as a microservice (but i think this is not really neccesarry on my question)

**Sample of JWT content**

```
{
  "iat": xxx,
  "exp": xxx,
  "roles": [
    "MY_ROLE"
  ],
  "id": "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE",
  "tenant": {
    "id": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555",
    "name": "MyTenant"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE",
    "username": "MyUser",
    "firstname": "My",
    "name": "User"
  }
}
```

**Sample of Entity: AbstractEntity.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use JsonSerializable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\IdGenerator\UuidGenerator;

/**
 * Class AbstractEntity
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity implements EntityInterface, JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UuidGenerator::class)
     */
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    /**
     * @return Uuid|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?Uuid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isNew(): bool
    {
        return !isset($this->id);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId()->toRfc4122()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return Uuid
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getId()->toRfc4122();
    }
}
```

**Sample of Entity: Settings.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Configuration;

use DateTime;
use App\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Configuration\SettingsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="configuration_settings", indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"tenant"})})
 */
class Settings extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var Uuid $tenant
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     */
    private Uuid $tenant;
  
    /**
     * @var string|null $payload
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private ?string $payload = "";

    /**
     * @return Uuid
     */
    public function getTenant(): Uuid
    {
        return $this->tenant;
    }

    /**
     * @param Uuid $tenant
     */
    public function setTenant(Uuid $tenant): void
    {
        $this->tenant = $tenant;
    }   

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPayload(): ?string
    {
        return $this->payload;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $payload
     */
    public function setPayload(?string $payload): void
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }
}
```

**Sample of Controller: SettingsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Configuration\API;

use App\Entity\Configuration\Settings;
use App\Entity\Security\Role;
use App\Repository\Configuration\SettingsRepository;
use App\Service\Security\UserService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

/**
 * Settings API controller.
 *
 * @Route("/api/configuration/settings", name="api_configuration_settings_")
 */
class SettingsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var SettingsRepository
     */
    private SettingsRepository $repository;

    /**
     * SettingsService constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Settings::class);        
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/obtain", name="obtain", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function obtain(UserService $userService, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorageInterface, JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager): JsonResponse
    {
        $userService->isGranted([
            Role::ROLE_TENANT_USER
        ]);

        $token = $jwtManager->decode($tokenStorageInterface->getToken());
        $tenantAsRFC4122 = $token['tenant']['id'];      // Here we have: 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
        $tenant = Uuid::fromString($tenantAsRFC4122);   // Here we have a class of Symfony\Component\Uid\UuidV6;

        $settings = $this->repository->findOneBy([
            'tenant' => $tenant
        ]);

        return new JsonResponse(
            $settings
        );
    }
}
```

If i now call the API-URL with the Authorization Header including the Bearer as JWT, i will get the Settings for my tenant 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555. But this works not always ...

I can't describe it exactly, because I can't reproduce it, but on one of the systems with a lot of traffic it happens from time to time that despite the correct bearer, i.e. correct tenant, simply wrong settings for another tenant come back.

Is there a doctrine cache somewhere that might cache queries and assign them to the wrong repsonses at the end of the day?

```
SELECT payload FROM configuration_settings WHERE tenant = '0x1234567890123456789' // here doctrine automaticly strips it to hex
```

I am so perplexed, because the SQL behind it looks correct and right, here times as an example shortened.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks,
S.

Comment: yes, doctrine have caching https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/caching.html and using in symfony caching pools https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers Doctrine have a three types of cache: query (DQL -> SQL queries cache), metadata (annotations/attributes -> php code cache) and result cache (result getting from cache, if doctrine thinks that's not necessary to query the db). Try to disable result cache (not recommended, it seems to me that's more like a bug, not cache problems).

Comment: just a wild guess, but in your controller´s `obtain` method the line `$userService->isGranted` AFAIS will do/prevent nothing unless wrapped in if-clause and return if false, if this is your actual code you might retrieve a token from a nongranted user which might lead to weird behaviour

Comment: I do not use the result cache within doctrine but i use the http cache and set all responses to public - could that maybe a problem?

Comment: @johnSmith my implementation of userService->isGranted throws an AccessDenied Exception, so the request will be terminated

Comment: @DerSausH Ok nevermind then ;) your code actually looks good to me. Your only option then probably is to somehow verbosely log  these "from time to time cases" to get a clue whats going wrong

Comment: I probably think i figure it out ... i used the prod http_cache from symfony and in my case i use etags to validate / invalidate the result. My fault was, that i set the response to public, so the symfony built in cache creates the files for my results and if there is a strange coincidence, maybe the wrong result is returned by the cache. I set cache to private, so symfony will not create any cache files for the built in cache - hope that works.